# Can I visually 'bypass' a View Controller completely via Segues?

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

[image: A Simple Storyboard Flow]

### Short Version

When I click on `confirm`, I want to segue to `Complete Purchase` and if the user does not have payment info on file, seque again directly to `Gather Payment Info` WITHOUT seeing the `Complete Purchase` View.  I am calling the second segue in `viewDidLoad` from `Complete Purchase` and I (briefly) see the `Complete Purchase` screen before it moves on.

### More Words

I have a fairly common scenario here; a purchasing capability with three different View Controllers.   In general, the user would click on `ShoppingCart.confirm` which causes a "Show" segue to `CompletePurchase`.   The user can then purchase (uninteresting here) or click on `CompletePurchase.EditPaymentInfo` which triggers a "Modal" segue to `GatherPaymentInfo`.  Dismissing `GatherPaymentInfo` would unwind back to `CompletePurchase` with the new payment info now available.

All of that is well and good but sometimes the user does not have any stored payment info.  What I want to do, *in CompletePurchase*, is to notice  that the user has no payment info and directly segue them to the `GatherPaymentInfo` controller.   When complete, the user dismisses as before, and they are ready to complete the purchase.

Even that is fine, as I perform the segue in `CompletePurchase.viewDidLoad()`.

The issue is that a user with no payment info sees the `CompletePurchase` screen briefly on the way to the `GatherPaymentInfo` screen.  I would like that transition to be seemless.

**Can I perform the second segue without the middleman (the `CompletePurchase`) being shown to the user?**

*I have already worked around the problem* by making the decision before the `ShoppingCart` -> `CompletePurchase` segue and performing a different segue but it feels very unclean.

Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish the mission here, I'd be interested in opinions on that as well as answers to the question - Thanks!

### Thing(s) that have not worked

I naively tried to just escape in `viewDidLoad()` :

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        if bad_condition == true {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: to, sender: self)
            return
        }
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

Which moves on as desired but not before showing the CompletePurchase view briefly.

Answer (score 1):

> I have already worked around the problem by making the decision before the ShoppingCart -> CompletePurchase segue and performing a different segue but it feels very unclean.

I think you're completely mistaken in your assessment. If you don't actually need the overhead of the CompletePurchase view controller in that situation, that is absolutely the cleanest possible solution! I'd say you should just move happily onward.

Comment: Well, as always, I appreciate it when people tell me I am completely mistaken :-).  But seriously, it does work as is.  There are other situations where I have desired this, largely so I can end up in the right place and not have to re-examine the state and redirect again.    You point is definitely taken though.  Thanks.

Comment: Consider what you'd do if there were no storyboards (which used to be the case). You'd have a condition deciding what view controller to instantiate and push. Choosing between storyboard segues is exactly parallel. I can't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Sure.  Fair enough.   What I am thinking here is that the 'state' of Complete Purchase needs to do the work of cart aggregation and payment info coordination.  Then it doesn't matter how I get to the CompetePurchase state, it will handle everything.   Admittedly a contrived requirement and I am very much dancing on the head of a pin.   I suspect it will be leaving it as is.